# Quasar - How to escape string in Datepicker mask?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I posted [this question](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/12896) to the Quasar Discussions awhile ago. I never figured out an answer, and put off this bug until now.

Essentially I've got a Datepicker component where a user can select a range of dates. On Select of those dates, I want the mask to format the string as "2 Days", or "1 Week", etc. Currently, because of the mask tokens, I am getting "2 Dfys". How can I escape the strings so that they show up correctly?

```vue
<template>
  <q-input
    v-model="stringifiedDate"
    outlined
    dense
    :mask="formattedDatepicker">
    <template #prepend>
      <q-icon
        name="bi-calendar-check"
        class="cursor-pointer">
        <q-popup-proxy
          ref="qDateProxy"
          cover
          transition-show="scale"
          transition-hide="scale">
          <q-date
            v-model="data.datepicker"
            range>
            <div class="row items-center justify-between">
              <q-btn
                v-close-popup
                label="Close"
                flat
                color="text"
                :ripple="false" />
                <q-btn
                  v-close-popup
                  label="Select"
                  :ripple="false"
                  color="primary"
                  flat />
              </div>
            </q-date>
        </q-popup-proxy>
      </q-icon>
    </template>
  </q-input>
</template>

<script lang='ts' setup>
  import {
    computed, reactive, ref, watch,
  } from 'vue';
  import dayjs from 'dayjs';
  import duration from 'dayjs/plugin/duration';
  import relativeTime from 'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime';

  dayjs.extend(duration);
  dayjs.extend(relativeTime);

  const data = reactive({
    datepicker: {
      from: undefined as string | undefined,
      to: undefined as string | undefined,
    },
  });

  const stringifiedDate = computed(() => JSON.stringify(data.datepicker));
  const formattedDatepicker = computed(() => {
    const from = dayjs(data.datepicker.from);
    const to = dayjs(data.datepicker.to);
    return dayjs.duration(from.diff(to))
      .humanize();
  });

  // set local data when dialog is opened
  watch(() => props.isOpen, () => {
    if (props.isOpen) {
      data.datepicker = {
        from: props.trip?.starting_date ? dayjs(props.trip.starting_date)
          .format('YYYY/MM/DD') : undefined,
        to: props.trip?.ending_date ? dayjs(props.trip.ending_date)
          .format('YYYY/MM/DD') : undefined,
      };
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the mask entirely, and setting the q-input's v-model to `formattedDatepicker`. This correctly displays the duration that I wanted to achieve, and I didn't have to figure out why escaping the mask characters wasn't working.

```vue
<template>
  <q-input
    v-model="formattedDatepicker"
    outlined
    dense>
    <template #prepend>
      <q-icon
        name="bi-calendar-check"
        class="cursor-pointer">
        <q-popup-proxy
          ref="qDateProxy"
          cover
          transition-show="scale"
          transition-hide="scale">
          <q-date
            v-model="datepicker"
            range>
            <div class="row items-center justify-between">
              <q-btn
                v-close-popup
                label="Close"
                flat
                color="text"
                :ripple="false" />
                <q-btn
                  v-close-popup
                  label="Select"
                  :ripple="false"
                  color="primary"
                  flat />
              </div>
            </q-date>
        </q-popup-proxy>
      </q-icon>
    </template>
  </q-input>
</template>
```